# Event ID: 7016 LitModeCtrl service has reported an invalid current state 32

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, event-log, event-viewer

I am getting all the time the below error in Windows Event Viewer. Throughout the web a lot of people get this error but there are no solutions to it. I was getting the error when i was using Windows 7 and now it is also appearing in Windows 8 Event Viewer. I get this Error at least 10 times every day! Any suggestions why I get the Error ? I can't find anything on Lenovo website about LitModeCtrl.exe.

#### Service Control Manager Event ID: 7016

> Message: The LitModeCtrl service has reported an invalid current state 32.

LitModeCtrl is located in `C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Power Dial\LitModeCtrl.exe`

---

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756305%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) are some more information's with **sc queryex**:

```
PS C:\Users\Devid\Desktop> sc.exe queryex LitModeCtrl

SERVICE_NAME: LitModeCtrl
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 3204
        FLAGS              :


PS C:\Users\Devid\Desktop> sc.exe interrogate LitModeCtrl

SERVICE_NAME: LitModeCtrl
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

**XML View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" 
                Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" 
                EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
      <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7016</EventID>
      <Version>0</Version>
      <Level>2</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Opcode>0</Opcode>
      <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-16T12:21:39.849666700Z" />
      <EventRecordID>269705</EventRecordID>
      <Correlation />
      <Execution ProcessID="876" ThreadID="2744" />
      <Channel>System</Channel>
      <Computer>Devid-Pavlicek</Computer>
      <Security />
   </System>
   <EventData>
      <Data Name="param1">LitModeCtrl</Data>
      <Data Name="param2">32</Data>
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

Some more information about the ID 7016 [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320789).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this error just uninstall Power Dial that was installed by Lenovo. There is no other solution.